# C++ Class/Structure size

Tags: c++, class, struct, sizeof

Hi I have some problem about the size of a class/struct
Here is my Graphnode.h, I only have 4 vars in it- one 16-unsigned char array, three unsigned char, I think the size should be 19. Why is it 32?

```
Graphnode currentNode; 
cout<< sizeof(currentNode)<<endl;// why this is 32 ?
cout<< sizeof(currentNode.state)<< endl;// this is 16
```

Graphnode.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tr1/array>

//using namespace std;
class Graphnode {

public:
    std::tr1::array<unsigned char, 16> state;
    unsigned char x;
    unsigned char depth;
    unsigned char direction;
    Graphnode(std::tr1::array<unsigned char, 16>,unsigned char,unsigned char, unsigned char);
    Graphnode();

};
Graphnode::Graphnode()
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
       state[i] = 0;
    }
    x = 0;
    depth = 0;
    direction = 0;
}

Graphnode::Graphnode(std::tr1::array<unsigned char, 16> _state,unsigned char _x,unsigned char _d,unsigned char _direction)
{   
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
       state[i] = _state[i];
    }
        x = _x;
        depth = _d;
        direction = _direction;
}
```

Comment: Just for curiosity, I would try to print the address of the different members of your structure to see how/where the space is wasted. I have the feeling that the compiler is assuming that your object needs to be aligned to 16 bytes and adding padding at the end. Try printing: `Graphnode g; std::cout << (void*)&g.state << "," << (void*)&g.x << "," << (void*)&g.depth << "," << (void*)&g.direction << "\n";` that should print three pointers, and the differences between them will tell you where the compiler is adding padding in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the compiler does not lay out the data structure members one directly after the other; it also leaves [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Data_structure_padding) in between.

Usually this means that any structure will be a multiple of some amount dependent on the types it contains and the target platform, even if the sum of the sizes of the fields is less.

All compilers typically [offer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) non-standard [extensions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html) that let you control this packing to a lesser or greater degree.

Comment: @weeo, that depends on what compiler you're using.

Comment: @weeo: Yes, I just expanded a bit.

Comment: Why do you think avoiding padding would be a good thing? In general, padding is added because the compiler thinks it's needed in one way or another, so to try to avoid it would probably break that intention of the compiler to "make things better".

Comment: @Jon One More question. there is no difference between C++ class and c struct nowadays. Is that correct? they are almost the same? I wonder if my code are in a good c++ form? THanks

Comment: @MatsPetersson I guess when you're messing up with too much data, the one to know best what's best is not the compiler (: Just a guess, though; I'd like to hear something else too ^^

Comment: @weeo: Well, C++ classes can contain methods and their default member visibility is `private`. Other than that, it's the same. Your code should not reference `tr1` at all, things are nicely inside namespace `std` nowadays.

Comment: @Jon I'm using array and unordered hash set from TR1, it's better now? I think the readin and out performance is better in TR1?